# Application ontime run only once when tiggered

Tags: excel, vba

The following code run only when tiggered and this code is in standard module1

```
                        Sub Macro1()

                            Calculate


                        End Sub


                        Sub start()

                            Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Macro1"

                        End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry Question is ...it runs only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could schedule a recurring event with the [Application.OnTime method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx), it may be best to avoid overrunning the timed procedure with a method like the following.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Calculate
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Macro1"
End Sub

Sub start()
    Macro1
End Sub
```